# not able to change highlight group setting in .vimrc

Tags: vim

I am trying to change the spellcheck highlight group. So in the end of my .vimrc

I add the following code

```
highlight clear SpellBad
highlight SpellBad cterm=underline
```

when I open a new file, it is still showing the old syntax highlighting.  But if I run the same commands inside vim manually after opened the file, it will work as expected.

Any idea what is going wrong here? Thanks!

Comment: The output `:verbose highlight SpellBad` tells you where the SpellBad was last set. It should be your `vimrc`. If not, you have to debug your setup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tweaks to a colorscheme have to happen *after* the colorscheme has been set. Usually, if you have the `:colorscheme` in your `~/.vimrc`, and put the `:highlight` commands after it, that should work.

Your case seems to be different (which could be caused by a plugin manager affecting the loading order, or you might even have a dynamically changing colorscheme). To handle such eventualities, you can instead hook into the [`ColorScheme`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/autocmd.txt.html#ColorScheme) event:

```
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight clear SpellBad
autocmd ColorScheme * highlight SpellBad cterm=underline
```

Comment: Thanks very much, it is caused by the dynamiclly changing colorscheme.